# render pandas generated plot to matplotlib canvas for streaming

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to stream a matplotlib generated through pandas df.plot() method  but having trouble to get the image rendered on the matplotlib canvas.

Here is what I am doing

```
import cStringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas


labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
s = pandas.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=labels)


fig = plt.figure()
s.plot()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
output = cStringIO.StringIO()
canvas.print_png(output)

fh=open('check.png','w')
fh.write(output.getvalue())
```

the check.png turns out to be blank. I think I am not able to render the plot generated by pandas plot function to canvas.

Second Try: see the axes but no data

```
import cStringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
s = pandas.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=labels)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
s.plot(ax=ax)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
output = cStringIO.StringIO()
canvas.print_png(output)


fh=open('check.png','w')
fh.write(output.getvalue())
```

Thanks!
-Abhi

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine but you must write the file in binary mode if you are working on a windows machine:

```
fh=open('check.png','wb')
```

Also, close the file after writing:

```
fh.close()
```

Your code above combined with these minor tweaks saves a read-able .png on my machine.